# How to get the number of input tags containing certain text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My goal is to flag when a user enters the same text into one input that matches at least one other input's text. To select all of the relevant inputs, I have this selector:

`$('input:text[name="employerId"]')`

but how do I select only those whose text = `abc`, for instance?

Here is my `change()` event that checks for duplicate text among all the inputs on the page. I guess I am looking for something like `:contains` but for text within an input.

```
var inputsToMonitorSelector = "input[type='text'][name='employerId']";
$(inputsToMonitorSelector).change(function() {
    //console.log($(this).val());
    var inputsToExamineSelector = inputsToMonitorSelector 
        + ":contains('" + $(this).val() + "')";
    console.log(inputsToExamineSelector);

    if($(inputsToExamineSelector).length > 1) {
        alert('dupe!');
    }
});
```

Or is there no such selector? Must I somehow select all the `inputsToMonitorSelector`'s and, in a function, examining each one's text, incrementing some local variable until it is greater than one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With input you need to use `[value="abc"]` or `.filter()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var textInputSelector = 'input[type="text"][name="employerId"]';
  $(textInputSelector).on('input', function() {
    $(textInputSelector).css('background-color', '#fff');
    var input = $(this).val();
    var inputsWithInputValue = $(textInputSelector).filter(function() {
      return this.value && input && this.value == input;
    });
    var foundDupe = $(inputsWithInputValue).length > 1;
    if(foundDupe) {
      console.log("Dupe found: " + input);
      $(inputsWithInputValue).css('background-color', '#FFD4AA');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="employerId" value="abc">
<input type="text" name="employerId" value="">
<input type="text" name="employerId" value="">
<input type="text" name="employerId" value="">
```

- `[value="abc"]` means if the value is `abc`
- `[value*="abc"]` `*` means if the value contains `abc`
- `[value^="abc"]` `^` means if the value starts with `abc`
- `[value$="abc"]` `$` means if the value ends with `abc`

**Note:** `:contains()` not for inputs , and word **text** not used with inputs and `<select>`.. inputs and `<select>` has a **value**

In your case .. instead of using

```
$(inputsToExamineSelector).length > 1)
```

You may need to use `.filter()`

```
$(inputsToExamineSelector).filter('[value*="abc"]').length > 1)
```

**OR**

```
$('input[type="text"][name="employerId"]').filter(function(){
    return this.value.indexOf('abc') > -1 
    // for exact value use >> return this.value == 'abc'
}).length;
```

And to use a variable on it you can use it like

```
'[value*="'+ valueHere +'"]'
```

Comment: I'd like for this to be the answer because it seems to be the most concise; however, `console.log($('input[type="text"][name="employerId"][value*="abc"]').length)` always gives me `0` when the input is after page load. Is it possible that `value` does not change in the DOM? Am I missing something? I tried it on an anchor `click` event and on the inputs' `change` events.

Comment: @CraigSilver you can use `.filter()` and `indexOf()` I update my answer with `<a>` click event but it keep output 1  and `input` input event instead of change event and with `filter()` and `indexOf()` it can update depending on the new values also you can use `.on('blur')` when out focus the input instead of `.on('input')`

Comment: That works. Thank you! I tweaked it on [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/craigsilver/egLc7vba/2/) to produce the desired result. Feel free to update yours in the answer.

Comment: Thank you @CraigSilver .. you're totally welcome .. Have a great day :-)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this works.  Attach `isDuplicated(myInputs,this.value)` to a `keyup` event listener attached to each input.

```
var myInputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='text']");

function isDuplicated(elements,str){
  for (var i = 0; i < myInputs.length; i++) {
    if(myInputs[i].value === str){
      myInputs[i].setCustomValidity('Duplicate'); //set flag on input
    } else {
      myInputs[i].setCustomValidity(''); //remove flag
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another one. I started with vanilla js and was going for an answer like Ron Royston with document.querySelector(x) but ended up with jquery. A first attempt at several things but here you go:

```
$("input[type='text']").each(function(){
    // add a change event to each text-element.
    $(this).change(function() {
        // on change, get the current value.
        var currVal = $(this).val();
        // loop all text-element-siblings and compare values.
        $(this).siblings("input[type='text']").each(function() {
            if( currVal.localeCompare( $(this).val() ) == 0 ) {
                console.log("Match!");
            }
            else {
                console.log("No match.");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xxx8we6s/